# PHP: getting error Cannot use object of type MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId as array?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

While printing values I am getting **error Cannot use object of type** MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId as array

Here is my print_r data

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
        (
            [oid] => 5f55f95815a8508e2deac8dd
        )

    [title] => Consumers to Gain as Telcos Cut Broadband Rates
    [summary] => Consumers are set to benefit from a broadband  
    [newsSources] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Consumers to Gain as Telcos Cut Broadband Rates
                    [articleId] => 003a0593-f0c3-11ea-98d1-1418779a6e32
                    [link] => https://myimpact.in/clipj_admin.php?id=95c14189533fa7c87a8ce6752cae40f5
                    [type] => print
                    [source] => The Economic Times - Kolkata
                     
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Data Plans Coming Much Cheaper with Telcos at War, Again
                    [articleId] => 3c4052f6-f0ac-11ea-959b-0068ebdc2fd0
                    [link] => https://myimpact.in/clipj_admin.php?id=95126ad546a574dd8233c2b0365d5f01
                    [type] => print
                    [source] => The Economic Times - Mumbai
                  
                )
```

**I am trying to access** [Source] from both array

Here is **my code** -

```
  foreach($cursor as $row){
                    //     echo"<pre>";
                  
                    //    print_r($row);
                  
                       foreach($row as $data) {
                        foreach($data['newsSources'][0] as $k) {
                              echo $k->source ;
                              
                        }
                 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` is an object. You need to use arrow syntax to access the properties.

```
foreach($data->newsSources as $item)
    echo $item->source;
```